# How to add a recurring story automatically to the new Sprint in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

We have a recurring story that should happen in every sprint.
In Service Now I know you can use Sprint Templates and achieve a similar result but now I am using Azure DevOps and I cannot find how to add a recurring story automatically to a sprint each time it is created.
The expected result is that whenever a new sprint is created the mentioned story and its tasks are contained in the sprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no such built-in features in Azure DevOps to automatically add a recurring user story to new Sprints.

There's already a suggestion ticket requesting a similar feature here : [Recurring work items](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/recurring-work-items/542666). You can go and vote up to achieve it in the future.

As mentioned in the suggestion ticket, as a workaround you can use excel to connect and deploy recurring work items manually when creating a new Sprint in Azure DevOps. See [Add or modify Azure Boards work items in bulk with Microsoft Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process) for details.

Comment: Is this still the case? Can the templates be used for this purpose?